# multi-tenancy solution with django

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I want to create a multi-tenant application where each tenant will have its own domain and database.

Domains will be like this: store1.saas.com, store2.saas.com .. and their respective databases will be store1 and store 2..

I have decided to name it as such so that depending upon on the url, i can set the database with some middleware.

I have tried https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas this but it wont work as it specifically asks to create a model inheriting from TenantMixin, which then is defined in settings like this.`TENANT_MODEL = 'catalogue.Product'`. I have multiple TenantModels and this scheme wont allow multiple models (it takes string and then uses split by "." and does their stuff based on it).

Trouble with me is

1. how to create sub-domains
2. how to test them in local, like store1.127.0.0.1:8000 wont work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try emulating the future real world as close as possible by editing your hosts file `/etc/hosts` and putting in there:

```
127.0.0.1 store1.saas.com
127.0.0.1 store2.saas.com
... etc
```

Then you can navigate to your localhost by store1.saas.com and so on.

Comment: how to do same in production environment.Will i have to edit /etc/hosts every time i create a tenant?

Comment: Normally in production you'd have a DNS server resolve it for you. E.g., you set up DNS to resolve *.saas.com to your server, so store1, store2 etc. will go there automatically; just as www.saas.com, www.store1.saas.com and so on.

Comment: i had to do something like this to make it work: store1.saas.com:8000

Comment: Well yeah, if your webserver runs on port 8000, then you'll have to put that in the URL as well ;-) But that would also apply if you'd run your app in production on port 8000, with the name resolved via a DNS server. Same difference.

Comment: but doing so stops my postgres server to start !! :(

Comment: Huh, I have a small problem understanding your comment... Doing what? What do you mean, stops my postgres server to start, does it start or stop, whatever you do..

Comment: how to do same in windows machine? like /etc/hosts